# Caching multiple controls on same page using VaryByControl

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to cache multiple controls on same page using `VaryByControl`. I would like you to tell me whether this approach is right.

```
      <%@ OutputCache Duration="1000" VaryByParam="None" VaryByControl="tbxFirstName;      tbxLastName;pbxMain;lstCountyID;tbxEmailAddress;tbxVerifyEmailAddress;tbxPromoCode;tbxPassword;tbxSecurityCode;cbxAgree" %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to cache properties of the control then you should have this

```
VaryByControl="WebUserControl.param1;WebUserControl.param2"
```

Comment: Here I am just trying to cache asp.net controls directly on a form but not specific properties of a control. I don't have user controls on page.Please help! Thanks